# Get Total Hour from different date time for OT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a data as below, it is a clock in and clock out date time for an employee

```
 ID        Start                End            taskId            EmployeeId
  1   2023-11-1 20:30:00  2023-11-2 00:30        2                  1
  2   2023-11-2 01:30:00  2023-11-2 05:30        2                  1
  3   2023-11-1 08:30:00  2023-11-1 12:30        2                  2
  4   2023-11-1 13:30:00  2023-11-1 17:30        2                  2
  5   2023-11-2 20:30:00  2023-11-3 00:30        2                  2
  6   2023-11-2 01:30:00  2023-11-3 05:30        2                  2
  6   2023-11-3 06:30:00  2023-11-3 11:30        2                  2
```

I need to calculate total working hour and over time for each employee.  Normal working hour is 8 hour, more than 8 hour will consider as OT.

Expected result as below

```
ID        Date     EmployeeId       Total Hour          OT
1      2023-11-1         1             8                 0
2      2023-11-1         2             8                 0
3      2023-11-2         2             13                5
```

I can't figure out how to get this expected result.  Any idea how I can write the query.  Thanks

***Morning shift start from 8:30am - 5:30pm. Night shift start from 8:30pm - 5:30am***

Comment: What's wrong with `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: Does interval of dates can overlaps? And if yes does this overlaps been collapsed ?

Comment: What is the **exact** data type of the Start and End columns?

Comment: Also, while it seems like this might be a learning problem, SQL Server 2012 has been formally end of life for more than 18 months now. That means it hasn't had any updates -- not even critical security patches! -- in quite a while. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it, especially for something as critical as payroll. And if it is a learning problem, it's silly to still be learning on such a dated version when newer versions are freely available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF(mi,[End],[Start])` to calculate the work time in minutes and sum it per date and employee. To sum per date, you can convert `Start` to a date with `cast([Start] as date)`. To get the total in hours, divide by 60. Overtime is the difference between the total and 480 (8*60 minutes).

```
SELECT
    Date,
    EmployeeID,
    SUM(Minutes)/60.0 As Total_Hours,
    IIF ( SUM(Minutes)>480, 
          SUM(Minutes)/60.0 - 8,
          0) as Overtime
FROM (SELECT
        cast([Start] as date) As Date,
        EmployeeID,
        DATEDIFF(mi,[End],[Start]) as Minutes
     FROM SomeTable
     ) As work_time
GROUP BY Date, EmployeeID
ORDER BY Date, EmployeeID
```

`IIF ( SUM(Minutes)>480` generates an Overtime value only if the total is above 480 minutes

Comment: Overtime shouldn't be negative.  I wouldn't use date as a column name (although it seems to work)

Comment: Oops, I forgot an IIF

Comment: Should be `SUM(Minutes)/60-8>0` ?

Comment: Double oops. I'm involved in another discussion where someone argues there's no point in JSON serializers because *their* code is never wrong

Comment: If night shift, the date will cross to next day, then it unable to SUM up the total hour for night shift worker.

Comment: @BubbleBub you never asked anything about *night* shifts. I answered what you actually asked. If you change the question from one year to the next, you invalidate all answers given to the original question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DATEDIFF` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID,
       CAST([START] AS DATE) AS DATE,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(mi,[End],[Start]))/60 as total_hour,
       case when SUM(DATEDIFF(mi,[END],[START]))/60 > 8 
            then SUM(DATEDIFF(mi,[END],[START]))/60 - 8 
       else 0 end as OT
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T
GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID, CAST([START] AS DATE)
ORDER BY DATE, EMPLOYEEID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The given answer by @Panagiotis_Kanavos and @ORA-01017 won't works if the interval of work is more than 1 complete day long...

By adding this row :

```
INSERT INTO ??? VALUES
(8, '2023-11-1 11:00:00', '2023-11-3 07:30', 2, 3);
```

Results from @Panagiotis_Kanavos and @ORA-01017, will be :

```
EmployeeID   Date         Total_Hours
------------ ------------------------
3            2023-11-01   44.500000
```

And not splits into 3 days...

In this case I use a calendar table or since 2022 version the GENERATE_SERIES table UDF.

Because @Bubble_Bub is on 2012 version, I will use a calendar table as :

```
CREATE TABLE T_CALENDAR_CLD
(CLD_ID          INT PRIMARY KEY,
 CLD_DATE        DATE UNIQUE);
GO

DECLARE @I INT = 1, @D DATE = '2020-01-01';
WHILE @I <= 10958
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO T_CALENDAR_CLD VALUES (@I, @D);
   SELECT @I = @I + 1, @D = DATEADD(day, 1, @D)
END;
```

Then one possible query to solve this problem is :

```
WITH 
T0 AS
(
SELECT *, 
       CASE
          WHEN CAST("Start" AS DATE) = CAST("End" AS DATE) 
             THEN DATEDIFF(second, "Start", "End")
          WHEN CAST("Start" AS DATE) = CLD_DATE
             THEN DATEDIFF(second, "Start", DATEADD(day,1,CLD_DATE))
          WHEN CAST("End" AS DATE) <= CLD_DATE
             THEN DATEDIFF(second, CLD_DATE, "End")
          ELSE 86400
       END / 3600.0 AS "hour"
FROM   T_PLANNING_PNG
       JOIN T_CALENDAR_CLD 
          ON CLD_DATE BETWEEN CAST("Start" AS DATE) AND CAST("End" AS DATE)
WHERE  DATEDIFF(second, "Start", CLD_DATE) <= 86400
   OR  DATEDIFF(second, CLD_DATE, "End") <= 86400
)
SELECT EmployeeID, CLD_DATE AS "DATE", 
       SUM("hour") AS total_hour, 
       SUM(SUM("hour")) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY CLD_DATE) AS cumulative_total_hour
FROM   T0
GROUP  BY CLD_DATE, EmployeeID
ORDER  BY EmployeeID, CLD_DATE;
```

The result is :

```
EmployeeID  DATE          total_hour     cumulative_total_hour
----------- ------------- -------------- -----------------------
1           2023-11-01    3.500000       3.500000
1           2023-11-02    4.500000       8.000000
2           2023-11-01    8.000000       8.000000
2           2023-11-02    14.500000      22.500000
2           2023-11-03    22.500000      45.000000
3           2023-11-01    13.000000      13.000000
3           2023-11-02    24.000000      37.000000
3           2023-11-03    7.500000       44.500000
```

**But wee still don't know what is OT and why the value is 5 for Employee-ID 2 for the last row...**

Comment: *"But wee still don't know what is OT and why the value is 5 for Employee-ID 2 for the last row..."* We do: *" Normal working hour is 8 hour, more than 8 hour will consider as OT."* `13 - 8 = 5`. Though doesn't specifically tell us what the acronym "OT" means (though I could guess), the important part is the definition of what it represents, which is defined.

Comment: @Thom Normal working hours depends on country you live. As an example in France it is 7. In many asiatic countries it is largely over 8...

Comment: Is 13 - 8 *not* 5 in France...? I'm not sure I follow your point? Integer maths with decimal values doesn't differ by country. Notation might be different, but the underlying logic is identical.

Comment: I do not know what OT means... And I do not see any definition of OT in @Panagiotis_Kanavos question...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can reliably capture what you are trying to with the information provided. There is no clear start of shift/end of shift. Also, there is no start of pay period and end of pay period for 40 hours.

Example outlier triggers: working a double, emergency shifts, change of shift mid workweek, etc. A peak season graveyard shift of 82 hours for a single week. An emergency shift that triggers a 36-hour shift. Working 4 days on the graveyard and then the 5th day changing to day shift. I see no way to cover these outliers without using flawed assumptions. Also consider nonstandard 8-hour shifts. For instance, a 4/10 (4 Days at 10 hours each). I am not sure how you would bind a variable shift range to a single 8 hour day rule without marking the actual start and end of shift.

That said, here is an alteration with a marked start of shift and end of shift.

Details: The from sub query gathers the start and end ranges using an added shift start/end. That then joins to the workhours to sum the totals and calculate OT.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by s.EmployeeId, s.ShiftStart) [ID],
    CAST(s.ShiftStart AS DATE) [Date],
    s.EmployeeId,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, wh.[Start], wh.[End])/60) [Total Hours],
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, wh.[Start], wh.[End])/60) > 8 
            THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, wh.[Start], wh.[End])/60) -8
        ELSE 0
    END AS [OT]
FROM(
    SELECT
        ShiftStart.[START] AS ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd.[END] AS ShiftEnd,
        ShiftStart.EmployeeId,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ShiftStart.EmployeeId order by ShiftStart.[START]) AS ShiftNumber
    FROM #tmp_workhours ShiftStart
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT 
            MIN(wh.[End]) [End]
        FROM #tmp_workhours wh
        WHERE wh.[End] > ShiftStart.Start 
          AND wh.eos = 1
          AND wh.EmployeeId = ShiftStart.EmployeeId
    ) AS ShiftEnd
    WHERE ShiftStart.sos = 1
) s -- shifts: start and end
JOIN #tmp_workhours wh ON wh.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId 
                      AND wh.[Start] >= s.ShiftStart 
                      AND wh.[End] <= s.ShiftEnd
GROUP BY s.EmployeeId, s.ShiftNumber, s.ShiftStart
ORDER BY s.EmployeeId
```

Result

| ID | Date | EmployeeId | Total Hours | OT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-01 | 1 | 8 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-11-01 | 2 | 8 | 0 |
| 3 | 2023-11-02 | 2 | 13 | 5 |

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_workhours(ID int, [Start] datetime, [End] datetime, taskId int, EmployeeId int, sos bit, eos bit)
INSERT INTO #tmp_workhours
VALUES
  (1, '2023-11-1 20:30:00', '2023-11-2 00:30', 2, 1, 1, 0),
  (2, '2023-11-2 01:30:00', '2023-11-2 05:30', 2, 1, 0, 1),

  (3, '2023-11-1 08:30:00', '2023-11-1 12:30', 2, 2, 1, 0),
  (4, '2023-11-1 13:30:00', '2023-11-1 17:30', 2, 2, 0, 1),

  (5, '2023-11-2 20:30:00', '2023-11-3 00:30', 2, 2, 1, 0),
  (6, '2023-11-3 01:30:00', '2023-11-3 05:30', 2, 2, 0, 0),
  (7, '2023-11-3 06:30:00', '2023-11-3 11:30', 2, 2, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Morning shift start from 8:30am - 5:30pm.  Night shift start from 8:30pm - 5:30am.

Comment: Sorry my mistake on the date time data.  I have modify the data.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I also updated the test data -- results are the same. BTW, your first column 6 needs the start updated from 2023-11-2 01:30:00 to 2023-11-3 01:30:00.

Comment: (3, '2023-11-1 08:30:00', '2023-11-1 12:30', 2, 2, 1, 0),
  (4, '2023-11-1 13:30:00', '2023-11-1 17:30', 2, 2, 0, 0),
  (5, '2023-11-1 18:30:00', '2023-11-1 20:30', 2, 2, 0, 1),
How about the EOS is 20:30 instead of 17:30

Comment: That would give employee 2's second shift a 10 hour day and 2 hours overtime. However line 5 was the start date for the 3 shift, so that will break the third shift.